# Cant perform any other actions while in loop

Tags: autohotkey

Functionality: I want the script to loop F5 to refresh the page for me and when I see something nice I press one of the other keys to snipe an item.

The problem: While its looping F5 I can't execute any of the other scripts.

````
MouseGetPos, OrigX, OrigY
mouseClick, left
sleep 20
random, randomlocx , 0,5
random, randomlocy , 0,5
MouseMove, 1162+randomlocx, 477+randomlocy, 0
mouseClick, left
sleep 10
send {y}
random, randomlocx2 , 0,10
random, randomlocy2 , 0,10
MouseMove, OrigX+randomlocx2, OrigY+randomlocy2, 0
return

2::
MouseGetPos, OrigX, OrigY
random, randomlocx , 0,5
random, randomlocy , 0,5
MouseMove, 964+randomlocx, 575+randomlocy, 0
sleep 20
mouseClick, left
MouseMove, OrigX, OrigY, 0

~$F5::
loop , 300 
{
Send {F5}
}   
return
F12::Reload   ; Reload script```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoHotkey doesn't provide true multithreading, so that's why your script isn't going to responsive while you have a loop running.
To get past this, you're going to want to use a [Timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm). A loop really isn't meant for this stuff.

Example of toggling a timer on/off with one key:

```
F5::
    toggle := !toggle ;a convenient way to toggle a variable in AHK, see below of explanation
    if(toggle) ;if true
        SetTimer, TimerCallback, 100 ;callback every ~100ms
    else
        SetTimer, TimerCallback, Off ;turn off timer
return

TimerCallback() ;the callback function
{
    Tooltip, % A_TickCount
}
```

Explanation for `toggle := !toggle` variable state toggling can be found from a previous answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59802702/3813732).
Also includes an example for a sweet little 1liner timer toggling hotkey.