# Autohotkey Toggle script

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I simply want to toggle the command with the same keymapping (Ctrl + I):

```
#InstallKeybdHook
#UseHook

^i::
send, BLABLABLA
return
```

If I press Ctrl+I, it types BLABLABLA(of course), and I want to make it repeated with a certain interval(180 sec) and I want it to be toggled. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use [a timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm).

And I'm not sure why you're using those two #directives, they're not doing anything useful for that script.

But about using a timer:
`SetTimer, TimerCallback, 180000`
This creates a timer that fires the function (or label) `TimerCallback` every 180,000 ms (180 sec).
Of course we're yet to define the function `TimerCallback`, so lets do that now:

```
TimerCallback()
{
     Tooltip, hi
}
```

And then to toggle the timer on/off on a hotkey:

```
^i::
     toggle := !toggle ;a convenient way to toggle a variable in AHK, see below of explanation
     if (toggle) ;if true
     {
          SetTimer, TimerCallback, 180000 ;turn on timer
          ;the function will only run for the first timer after 
          ;those 180 secs, if you want it to run once immediately
          ;call the function here directly:
          TimerCallback()
     }
     else
          SetTimer, TimerCallback, Off ;turn off timer
return
```

Explanation for `toggle := !toggle` variable state toggling can be found from a previous answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59802702/3813732).
Also includes an example for a sweet little 1liner timer toggling hotkey.

---

And here's the full example script:

```
^i::
     toggle := !toggle ;a convenient way to toggle a variable in AHK, see below of explanation
     if (toggle) ;if true
     {
          SetTimer, TimerCallback, 180000 ;turn on timer
          ;the function will only run for the first timer after 
          ;those 180 secs, if you want it to run once immediately
          ;call the function here directly:
          TimerCallback()
     }
     else
          SetTimer, TimerCallback, Off ;turn off timer
return

TimerCallback()
{
     Tooltip, hi
}
```