# AHK Click event while Toggled

Tags: autohotkey

I've found AHK codes that separately work "ok" but I need one inside another. So, I have:

**1. The first** rapidly fires click when you hold down the left mouse button:

```
~$LButton::
    While GetKeyState("LButton", "P"){
    Click
    Sleep .1  ;  milliseconds
    }
return
```

**2. The second** is a toggle script that sends the same left mouse button firing events but can be toggled on and off with a button press (F8 in this case)

```
toggle = 0
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

F8::
    Toggle := !Toggle
    While Toggle{
        Click
        sleep 1
    }
return
```

**What I need is:** when I push F8 once, I want my left mouse button to fire click events rapidly while holding it. When I push F8 again it should do nothing. If it's important, I need those clicks while holding Ctrl in-game.
I've read a bit about AHK and tried this code but it doesn't work any close to what I want:

```
toggle = 0
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

F8::
    Toggle := !Toggle
    If Toggle{
~$LButton::
    While GetKeyState("LButton", "P"){
    Click
    Sleep .5  ;  milliseconds
    }
    }
return
```

This one gives me errors about missing "return" but I tried a lot of merging variations.

*Also, I've read a lot about MaxThreads and still don't know why there should be 2 and what is it for.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, not sure what amount of time you're trying to give the [`Sleep`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm) commands, but decimal numbers wont work. Just whole numbers, and they're in milliseconds. `.1` and `.5` are likely interpreted as `0`, not sure though. Also, the sleep command isn't as accurate as you may think it is. Read the remarks section in the documentation for more.

Secondly, you shouldn't loop inside hotkey labels. It's bad practice due to AHK not offering true multithreading.
Though, at the end of the day, it wont make any difference if this is all your script it.
For future reference if you want to start writing nicer and bigger scripts, I'll show you the usage of [timers](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) though. They should be used for this.

```
LButton::SetTimer, MyCoolFunction, 0 ;when LButton is clicked down start a timer with the shortest possible period
LButton Up::SetTimer, MyCoolFunction, Off ;when LButton is released, stop the timer

MyCoolFunction()
{
    Click
}
```

And same for your toggle version, you don't want to loop inside a hotkey label:

```
F8::
    toggle := !toggle
    if(toggle) ;if true
        SetTimer, MyCoolFunction, 0
    else
        SetTimer, MyCoolFunction, Off
return

MyCoolFunction()
{
    Click
}
```

And if you don't know what `toggle := !toggle` actually is, and want to know, you can read a previous answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800543/how-to-stop-the-current-script/59802702#59802702). It also shows how you can compact that code down to just one line of code. And also explains why there's no need to define the variable `toggle` on top of your script (as you were doing).

And about [`#MaxThreadsPerHotkey`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MaxThreadsPerHotkey.htm)`2`:
It's because AHK doesn't offer true multithreading. When you're looping side a hotkey definition, that hotkey is completely locked up. You can't run the hotkey again to stop the loop. Unless, you set the hotkey to use more *threads* (better to call them instances) than one.
That way you're able to launch the hotkey again and you're able to change the `toggle` variable's value so you can stop the loop.
But again, you shouldn't loop inside hotkeys. If you use a timer, like I showed above, you don't need to worry about this dirty workaround.

---

And then to the new code you want to create.
Well first about what went wrong in your attempt. I guess it was a good thought, but it's not even close. Hard to say what exactly is wrong in it, since it's not even close to working. I guess what I can say is that hotkey labels (`hotkey::`) are evaluated once when the script starts, and then never again. So you can't put them inside some runtime logic. The [`Hotkey`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) command would be used for that.

Luckily your problem is actually much simple than that. You don't need to mess around with the `Hotkey` command.
All you're looking to do is toggle the hotkeys on/off. [`Suspend`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm) is used for that like so:
`F8::Suspend`
And now the script's hotkeys (and hotstrings) toggle on/off every time you press F8.

So here's your final script:

```
LButton::SetTimer, MyCoolFunction, 0 ;when LButton is clicked down start a timer with the shortest possible period
LButton Up::SetTimer, MyCoolFunction, Off ;when LButton is released, stop the timer

MyCoolFunction()
{
    Click
}

F8::
    Suspend
    SetTimer, MyCoolFunction, Off ;set the timer off just incase we hadn't released LButton before we hit F8
return
```

Comment: I'm very grateful but it doesn't solve the task.
From scratch - I need a script that toggles on/off, so it doesn't affect anything at all until toggled on.
When toggled on, it should constantly and fast send clicking events while I'm pressing left mouse button.
What it should actually solve for me: I'm playing Path of Exile, there's an inventory with 5x12 grid. When you trade, you can Ctrl-click on item to send it. So, for full inventory you need 60 clicks. I want to toggle on script, hold Ctrl, press mouse button and just mouseover whole grid.

Comment: This is exactly what the code in the answer does. Maybe that `Ctrl` part was why you thought it didn't. Use the [`*`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard) modifier to your hotkeys so they fire even when extra modifiers are held down. (Example: `*LButton::`)

Comment: With the "*" it works exactly as it should! I also added "    Suspend
    SetTimer, MyCoolFunction, Off" to be disabled at start - is it sloppy or ok?

Comment: If you want it to start off suspended, sure you can make `Suspend` the first line of the script. Wont need the extra check there to turn off the timer though.