# How do I send output to an inactive window for better AFK? (AutoHotkey)

Tags: automation, keyboard, autohotkey, keypress

I'm trying to send the output of my code to an inactive application using Auto Hotkey on my computer so I don't have to be on the screen and can do other stuff. How would I go about implementing it?

```
F1::
stop := 0
Loop
{
    Send, z
    Sleep 500
}until Stop
return

F2::Stop := 1
```

This is the code I have down so far, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ControlSend`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)ing might work. It's basically a hit or miss. It'll work for some applications, and for some it wont.
It'll be worth a try for you though.

Also, you're going to want to use a [timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) as opposed to looping in a hotkey thread. Timer is intended just for something like this and what you were doing is kind of bad practice for various reasons.

```
;timer runs the user-defined function "SendZ" every 500ms
F1::SetTimer, SendZ, 500 
F2::SetTimer, SendZ, Off

SendZ()
{
    ControlSend, , z, % "ahk_exe notepad.exe"
}
```

---

As a bonus, we can even write a sweet one liner to toggle on/off that timer by using a ternary:
`F1::SetTimer, SendZ, % (Toggle:=!Toggle) ? 500 : "Off"`
If that doesn't make sense to you, and you're interested, you can read a lengthy previous explanation of mine about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800543/how-to-stop-the-current-script/59802702#59802702).