# Multiple loops with timers

Tags: autohotkey

So I'm new to AutoHotkey and I'm having some issues with the Multiloop timer thing, it works fine as first but on the second loop forward the times don't match up with what I want.

So basically I want the loops to run for 5min the loopTwo should be the first one out after 7s and then 2 seconds later I want the loopOne to be called in loopOne I have a 1.2s delay between presses, the first time it works correctly but then the times starts to shift and everything joins in a mess

```
F1::
If (loopOne = True) 
{
    SetTimer loopTwo, Off
    TwoSwitch  := False
    SetTimer loopOne, Off
    OneSwitch := False
} else {
    TheTwoTime := 0
    SetTimer loopTwo, 7000 ;run every 7s
    TwoSwitch := True
    TheOneTime := 0
    SetTimer loopOne, 9000 ;run every 9s
    OneSwitch := True
}
return


loopOne:
    Send, 1
    Sleep, 1200
    Send, 1
    TheOneTime ++
    If TheOneTime >= 300 ;run for 5 minutes
    {
        SetTimer loopOne, Off
        OneSwitch := False
    }
return

loopTwo:
    Send, 2
    Sleep, 2000
    TheTwoTime ++
    If TheOneTime >= 300 ;run for 5 minutes
    {
        SetTimer loopTwo, Off
        TwoSwitch := False
    }
return
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that the logic of your code is functioning as intended, but you are having issues with getting the timing of the loops to run correctly?

Comment: Yes, the first time it runs exactly loopTwo in 7s > loopOne in 9s (2s after the loopTwo) , the then the too loops get weird start coming too early and mixed up, and what i want is 7s > 9s (2s after first) > 7s > 9s like a repetition for x Time in this case 5min

Comment: So you want loopOne to always activate 2s after loopTwo?

Also, FYI, the first loop runs for 1200*300=360,000 ms = 6 mins, whereas the second loop runs for 2000*300= 600000ms = 10 mins. If you want me to explain why, lmk, It has to do with the fact that the counter cannot increment while the script is Sleeping

Comment: Yes that what i want
So the sleeps are a problem down there

Comment: If your intended result is to have both of the loops run for five minute stretches, then yes. In the past, when I have had issues like this, I would just use a setTimer function inside of the main functions (ie. loopOne and loopTwo) in order to trigger another function (such as flipOne and flipTwo), causing the main functions to return after the correct time. (since the setTimer function doesn't stall the program like Sleep does)

Comment: Can you pick what i have up there and make an example so i can understand it better?

Comment: Sure, Im kindof busy tho rn, so I'll take a shot at it later tonight if nobody else has posted a valid solution to it by then.

Comment: Some misinformation here. There's nothing wrong with sleeping the thread. That wont affect the timer's period. It'll tick down the same. Only thing wrong with the script is the logic. Both of the loops will run for 300 iterations, which is 45mins for the first loop and 35mins for the second. And running one thing every 7sec and another every 9sec wont make them happen 2secs apart every time, not even close. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/Hj5xuJp.png) visualization for example. Seems to me you should just   have one loop with sleeps, it'll be simple that way. See the answer I'm about to post.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were trying to do. I don't see any need for two timers, assuming I understood your thing correctly.

Also ditched the legacy labels and switched over to [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) due it to being the preferred faster and more reliable send mode.
Should be a pretty straight forward script apart from toggling with `toggle:=!toggle`. If you can't understand it, you can see an old answer of mine that has a bit about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800543/how-to-stop-the-current-script/59802702#59802702).
Also note the usage of a negative period in a timer, it's a very useful thing.

```
F1::
    if (toggle:=!toggle)
    {
        SetTimer, MyCoolLoop, 7000 ;7sec period
        SetTimer, StopLooping, -300000 ;negative period, run ONCE after 5mins
    }
    else
        SetTimer, MyCoolLoop, Off
return

MyCoolLoop()
{
    ;number 2 gets sent (every 7secs)
    ;2secs after this, number 1 gets sent
    ;1.2secs after this, number 1 gets sent again
    ;3.8secs after this, we start from the beginning
    SendInput, 2
    Sleep, 2000
    SendInput, 1
    Sleep, 1200
    SendInput, 1
}

StopLooping()
{
    SetTimer, MyCoolLoop, Off
}
```

Comment: I think that was my problem, thanks for explaining it, I have on question tho tho, the 3.8s to complete the 7 if i want noghing to be sent i just need to sleep for 3.8s right? and if i want to make it 10s por exemple i just need to up that sleep 6.8s right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, but it sounds wrong. You're not supposed to add any additional extra sleeps.

Comment: I going to try to explain better so, i want to run that loop for 5min and then stop that part its ok for now and i need to run MyCoolLoop every 7s, for now it runs for 3.2s and it start from the begining agin what i think i should do is change this way maybe

`SetTimer, MyCoolLoop, 7000` and after last sendinput add `Sleep, 3800` and i wrong?

Comment: You don't need to add any extra Sleeps. The code in MyCoolLoop() gets executed every 7 seconds. Any Sleeps you add to the end there are of no use. The 3.8sec thing I mentioned just means that after 2000+1200 ms has elapsed, there's 3800ms left in the 7sec period until the code gets executed again.

Comment: I understood I think it's in the logic of thinking that I am falling, maybe i miss explained what I want to archive but it's close tho